# Equivalent POST and GET from HttpServlet to REST

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jax-rs

I am trying to understand the equivalent way of mimicking HttpServlet to a Restful webservice.

---

I have the following HttpServlet code :

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
      String reqXml = req.getParameter("xmlrequest");
   }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
      String reqXml = req.getParameter("xmlrequest");
   }

}
```

---

I am trying to do the equivalent way in REST.

Here is my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/getInfo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getDetails(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String xmlRequest = request.getParameter("xmlrequest");
}



@GET
@Path("/getInfo")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getDetails(@FormParam("xmlrequest") String request) {
    String xmlRequest = request.getParameter("xmlrequest");
}
```

---

Comment: I showed effort in researching, wrote a clear specific question and showed my work and yet I still get two down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing POST request, generally the parameters will come as part of the request body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data

```
POST /api/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

key1=value1&key2=value2
```

On the server you would use the `@POST` annotation to signify that the endpoint is for a POST request. To get the parameter value, you would use `@FormParam`. With the above request, you would do

```
@POST
@Comsumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response post(@FormParam("key1") String key1, @FormParam("key2") String key1) {}
```

For GET request, the parameters will come as part of the URL in form of the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

```
GET /api/endpoint?key1=value1&key2=value2 HTTP/1.1
```

On the server you would use `@GET` to signify that the endpoint is for GET requests. You would get the parameter values with the `@QueryParam` annotation

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response get(@QueryParam("key1") String key1, @QueryParam("key2") String key1) {}
```

When to use query params and form params depends on the situation. Generally you use form params when you are trying to submit/send data to the server. For example you want to save information about a new user. You would send a POST request with the data sent as form parameters. You generally use query parameters when you are trying to *retrieve* information from the server, and query parameters server as some filtering mechanism. For example you want to get a list of users and you want to get just the first 10. You might make a GET request to users endpoint with a `limit=10` parameter in the URL `/api/users?limit=10`

---

If you want to send XML data, you don't want to use form parameters. What you are showing in your code it's as if you are trying to send XML data inside form parameters, like

```
POST /api/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

xmlrequest=<user>Paul</user>
```

When you do

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
   String reqXml = req.getParameter("xmlrequest");
}
```

then the value of the `reqXml` would be the XML string `<user>Paul</user>`. This is very odd and is not how you should be doing it. The XML should be send as the main request body, and the `Content-Type` should be `application/xml`.

```
POST /api/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml

<user>Paul</user>
```

To get the data in a servlet, you would need to read the input stream. You couldn't get the data with `getParameter()`

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    InputStream xmlStream = req.getInputStream();
    String xml = readStream(xmlStream);
}
```

In a JAX-RS endpoint, you could get the whole XML string simply by having a String parameter

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response post(String xmlString) {}
```

With the last request, the value of `xmlString` would be `<user>Paul</user>`.

When working with XML in JAX-RS, generally you will be working with [POJOs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pojo-vs-java-beans/). Let say you have this XML

```xml
<User>
  <firstName>Jane</firstName>
  <lastName>Doe</lastName>
</User>
```

What we want to do is map it to a POJO, mapping the different XML elements and attributes to the POJO properties. For example, wit the above Xml, we would map it to the following POJO

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    public String getLasttName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
}
```

Now in our resource method, we could just accept a `User` as parameter

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response post(User user) {
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Great, ty! This worked for me when I added it as a @QueryParam